# Preferred way to Build/Test/Deploy docker images in GitLab CI/CD

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab-ci, bitnami

I am trying to build a CI/CD pipeline in GitLab. The goal is to build a docker image from a Dockerfile, run tests on the running container, push the image to DockerHub, then deploy it to a Kubernetes cluster. This is what I currently have for my `gitlab-ci.yml`.

```yaml
variables:
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  CONTAINER_IMAGE: ${DOCKER_USER}/my_app

services:
  - docker:19.03.12-dind

build:
  image: docker:19.03.12
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo ${DOCKER_PASSWORD} | docker login --username ${DOCKER_USER} --password-stdin
    - docker pull ${CONTAINER_IMAGE}:latest || true
    - docker build --cache-from ${CONTAINER_IMAGE}:latest --tag ${CONTAINER_IMAGE}:$CI_COMMIT_SHA --tag ${CONTAINER_IMAGE}:latest .
    - docker push ${CONTAINER_IMAGE}:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - docker push ${CONTAINER_IMAGE}:latest

deploy:
  image:
    name: bitnami/kubectl:1.16.15
    entrypoint: [""]
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  script:
     - kubectl get pods -A   # <- Won't work until I pass a Kubeconfig file with cluster details
```

I have a few main questions:

1. How can I deploy this image? I know I need to pass a KUBECONFIG file to bitnami/kubectl, but not sure how to do that with GitLab CI/CD
2. Can I pass the built image to a **test** stage before pushing to DockerHub

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an answer for deploying to Kubernetes, but I do recommend publishing a test/construction image to Dockerhub when working a merge request/development branch of building the image. Then only deploy the latest image when you merge the branch to master .

```
---
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build image:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build your_iamge:test
    - deploy push your_image:test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != "master"

test image:
  stage: test
  image: your_image:test
  script:
    - commands to test image
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != "master"

deploy image:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - docker build your_image:latest
    - docker push your_image:latest
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master"
```

```
---
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build image:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build your_image:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    - deploy push your_image:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != "master"

test image:
  stage: test
  image: your_image:test
  script:
    - commands to test image
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != "master"

deploy image:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - docker build your_image:latest
    - docker push your_image:latest
    - export BRANCH=${CI_COMMIT_TITLE#*\'}; export BRANCH=${BRANCH%\' into*}
    - docker delete your_image:$BRANCH
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master"
```

Comment: I like the idea so that I don’t have a thousand tags in dockerhub, but won’t this create a race condition if two people are running the pipeline at the same time?

Comment: Yes, if there are multiple pipelines running for this image build project, they will be overwritten by the most recent pipeline. 

If this will be a common occurrence for the project, you can instead of using the tag “test”,  use the branch name as a tag in the build job. Then in the deploy job you delete the image tagged with the branch name (to avoid a lot of tagged images existing in dockerhub).

Comment: I added a second yml set up to the answer. This should build your images using the branch as the tag, and then for the deploy job it manipulates the CI_COMMIT_TITLE to get the branch being merged in and delete the image with that branch tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
---
stages:
  - test app
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

test app:
  stage: test_app
  image: node:latest
  script:
    - git clone (path to code)
    - npm install 
    - lint
    - audit fix
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != "master"
    
build image:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build your_image:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    - deploy push your_image:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != "master"

test image:
  stage: test
  image: anchor:latest  (one you have built yourself or use another testing suite)
  script:
    - anchore-cli image add user/image:v1
    - anchore-cli image wait user/image:v1
    - anchore-cli image content user/image:v1
    - image vuln user/image:v1 all
    - anchore-cli evaluate check user/image:v1 > result .txt
    - if ( grep -ci "fail" result.txt >= 1); then exit 1 fi  
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != "master"

deploy image:
    image:
        name: kubectl:latest  (build your own image that installed kubectl)
        entrypoint: [""]
    stage: deploy
    tags:
        - privileged
    # Optional: Manual gate
    when: manual
    dependencies:
        - build-docker
    script:
        - kubectl config set-cluster k8s --server="$CLUSTER_ADDRESS"
        - kubectl config set clusters.k8s.certificate-authority-data $CA_AUTH_DATA
        - kubectl config set-credentials gitlab-service-account --token=$K8S_TOKEN
        - kubectl config set-context default --cluster=k8s --user=gitlab-service-account --namespace=my-service
        - kubectl config use-context default
        - kubectl set image $K8S_DEPLOYMENT_NAME $CI_PROJECT_NAME=$IMAGE_TAG
        - kubectl rollout restart $K8S_DEPLOYMENT_NAME
```

```
1. have variables passed in for cluter address, cert data, and token stuff... so you can target other clusters, pre-prod, prod, qa...

2. you can't test an image that isn't on the repo, as the testing suite needs to pull the image from somewhere... You should have a clean up script running to cleanup old image in your repo anyway, so the initial push should be a (test location)

like:  docker push untrusted/image:v1

You should also have before scripts and after scripts... before calls docker login
after calls docker logout...
```